# Choose which textbox console.readline reads from?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I'm writing a code in C# where the user enters a number into a textbox named `inputOne` and then another number in `inputTwo` and then I can convert them to string and then an int so they can either add/subtract/divide/multiply the two numbers and then the program will display it on the `finalAnswer` textbox.

The only way I know of how to pull data from a textbox is to use the `Console.ReadLine();` command. I don't know how to choose which textbox to read from. Is this possible?

Comment: What type of application is this? Windows application? Web application?

Comment: Do you need to keep the console window as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Console.ReadLine` is when you are reading input for a Console application.  It sounds like you are designing a `Windows Forms` application here so you need to use the `Text` property on the Textbox control.

To access this you can do:

```
string userInput = Textbox1.Text;
string userInput2 = Textbox2.Text;
```

You can also rename these controls (Via the designer if you're using Visual Studio) to something more appropriate.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help. Would Textbox1 be what I named the textbox for the user to enter in the number?

Comment: @user2781666 - yes.  By default it's called that but you can change it  by clicking on the textbox and looking for the `Name` property on the control (If you're using Visual Studio)

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. Is their a site where I can find information like this? I've found some basic tutorial stuff for programming but not really anything with C#

Comment: @user2781666 - great, please accept this as the answer.  You can look at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ - or just google Windows Forms tutorials.